# How to find a name in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Can anyone help me to find a string in the word, i.e, how to search any part of the name in datagridview? for eg. RamGopalVarma, if i type only varma in search option it should find in gridview.

Below is my code which is working only when I give total name. When I change "Equals" into "Contains" it's not working.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
  dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
  // Code to search the  alphanumneric Part Number (in Column1 header called "Name") and highlihgt the row
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
  {
    if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox3.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Need a bit more details re "which is working only when I give total name."

Comment: why don't you use [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) and let the user search using it's own browser? you have so much already im place, all you need is to format your `datagrid` appropriately

Comment: @MSI:for eg., if we have a name called "Rajkumar". When I type total name(Rajkumar) in the search box, then only it is showing in the dgv. If I type only Raj in the search box, the result is nothing.

Comment: @balexandre: Actually I've a requirement in the gridview. Searching in Google longtime, I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I suggest you don't search the GridView - search the data which is bound to the GridView. You can then easily find the corresponding row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the .Equals method has an option to ignore case, whereas the .Contains method is case-sensitive.  You could try something like:

```
if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant().Contains(textBox3.Text.ToUpperInvariant()))
{
// do something
}
```

If it were me, I'd perform convert textBox3 text to upper only once, before the loop.

Comment: thank you much Rick, it's been long time form me to find this solution. I appriciate much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Pravii

```
if (row.Cells["Name"].FormattedValue.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
```

or search all cells...

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
      foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
      {
            if(c.FormattedValue.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {
                //do your work.....
            }         

      }
 }
```

Try this pravii

```
if(c.FormattedValue.ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
```

Comment: Hi terrybozzio: the above code is working, but how do i ignore case sentivity?

Comment: Hi terrybozzio, how are you doing.
I need your help again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Contains like:

```
if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox3.Text))
{
  ...the rest of the code if match
}
```

Comment: Hi Edper, the search word should be dynamic, not static. The user will search any name from the serch option dynamically.

Comment: @Pravii just change to textBox3.Text the value inside the Contains so that it would be dynamic. Check my updated code.

Comment: how about ignoring case senstivity. How do i turn it off?

Comment: after ToString() you use ToLower() like ToString().ToLower().Contains(textBox3.Text)

Comment: got it Edper, thank you much. I used the below code 


if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().ToUpperInvariant().Contains(textBox3.Text.ToUpperInvariant()))

Comment: Glad that it works for you @Pravii. Happy coding and GOD bless.